# Difference between preprocessor directives #error and #warning

Tags: c, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor, compiler-warnings

In these two preprocessor codes, what is their difference and how are they used?

```
#error "¡ERROR GRAVISIMO!"

#warning "ABC está obsoleto. Use XYZ en su lugar."
```

Comment: These are no macros. And only one of the directives is standard C. Hint: it is not the second one.

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation from your compiler? [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Diagnostics.html) for example says: "The directive ‘#error’ causes the preprocessor to report a fatal error...The directive ‘#warning’ is like ‘#error’, but causes the preprocessor to issue a warning and continue preprocessing."

Comment: Maybe you forgot there is a search engine called [google](https://www.google.com). **Do some effort** and read the  [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and [GNU CPP](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

`#error` is used to create errors, which keep the program from compiling. `#warning` produces a compiler warning, but doesn't keep the program from compiling. Here are two screenshots that illustrate that:

Error:

[image]

Warning:

[image]

Notice that in the first case the build failed and in the second case the build finished successfully.

`#error` is used when you want to keep the program from compiling in certain conditions, usually because the program won't work properly then, and `#warning` is used if the program should be able to compile but might not work properly and you want to help the user know why.

The following examples produce an error or a warning if the program is compiled in C++ mode instead of C mode. Note that C++ compilers automatically create the macro `__cplusplus`.

Error:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #error This program isn't compatible with C++!
#endif
```

Warning:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #warning You are compiling this as a C++ program, but it's recommended to compile it as a C program.
#endif
```

The first code is used for programs which don't support C++ and the second code is used for programs which may have a strange behavior in C++ but which still support it. These are of course just examples of how to use `#error` and `#warning`.